# How to create custom validation rule in Laravel 6 API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-api

I need to use my custom validation rule for validating API requests.

**Request Class:**

This is my request validation rule.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'username.required' => 'The Username field is required',
            'password.required'  => 'The Password field is required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**API Controller:**

This is my API controller and method.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\BaseController as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;

class LoginController extends BaseController
{
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        print_r($validatorMsg);
        die();
    }
}
```

Unable to get error message.

Comment: and what is not working?

Comment: Unable to get an error message.

Comment: You don't need to print $validatorMsg, just provide a false data in your form, and Laravel will handle errors by itself.

Comment: @zlatan In the API I am not getting an error message. how can I return the error message in JSON format?

Comment: For an ajax request, it should automatically return a JSON response. Nothing looks wrong in your code. Can you show us the response returned from the server?

Comment: @Rehmat when I run it on postman getting login page HTML code but I need to JSON response.

Comment: @PiyushShukla Looks like you are posting to a wrong route. Can you show your routes? You will have to double check and ensure that you are making a correct request (by type) to a correct route.

Comment: @Rehmat routes are fine. When I am using the default validator method it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys, I resolved the problem this is the solution:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $LoginRequest = New LoginRequest;
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $LoginRequest->rules(),$LoginRequest->messages());

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to display error messages in your API's, use `response()` method in your `LoginRequest` class, so you always return JSON. Something like this:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
     // Always return JSON.
     return response()->json($errors, 422);
}
```

Now try to submit empty form, and you should be able to view the error message.